# Should I map an array if there is only one object in it?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am trying to use data I fetch from an Api in a react project. The api returns an array with only one object, but that object has many properties I need to use in the jsx.

My question is more about efficiency/best practice. Should I map the array or just call index 0.

This is within the return of the component. Just to reiterate the array only has the ONE object which has a bunch of properties.

```
array.map((obj) => (
   <p>{obj.id}</p>
   <p>{obj.name}</p>
   <p>{obj.other}</p>
   <p>{obj.title}</p>
)) 

or

<p>{array[0].id}</p>
<p>{array[0].name}</p>
<p>{array[0].other}</p>
<p>{array[0].title}</p>
```

Comment: A benefit of `map()` would be if you use the same callback elsewhere. But it also hints at there being multiple items in the array. Using `obj[0]` is pretty straightforward and simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling index 0 would be slightly more performant than starting an iteration, getting the one object, then stopping the iteration. However if you will ever expect there to be more than one object then you will need map.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks for the swift response!

Comment: In my scenario it will only ever be the one object.

Comment: @2bootylicious: You may want to check that, even so, so if the API ever changes, you aren't silently ignoring the rest of the response.

Comment: It is generally a really bad pattern to grab something out of an Array by index when rendering content from an api request. If it is ever only one item, then you should at the place where you make the api request return the single item out of the array down to the view. This way you are working directly with the object

Answer (score 3):

If the API is not going to change, and always return an array with an entry, just set your state accordingly:

```js
fetch('/api')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => setSomething(data[0]))
```

If the API can return multiple entries, you will need `.map()` for semantics.